# How to install sshfs on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint, package-management, software-installation, sshfs

I am trying to install `sshfs` on Linux Mint to mount remote folders over SSH. I've Googled up and down on how to install `sshfs` (as the command is not available to me) and I'm beating my head against the wall because I cannot find the repository it is in.

```
~ $ sshfs
The program 'sshfs' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt-get install sshfs
~ $ sudo apt-get install sshfs
[sudo] password for XXXX: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sshfs
```

**Edit:** Adding response to @Nate from Kalamazoo's answer here for code formatting:

```
~ $ sudo apt-get install sshfs-fuse
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package sshfs-fuse
~ $ apt-cache search sshfs
~ $
```

**Edit:** Adding output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`:

```
deb http://packages.linuxmint.com/ olivia main upstream import
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/dockbar-main/ppa/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/dockbar-main/ppa/ubuntu raring main
### THIS FILE IS AUTOMATICALLY CONFIGURED ###
# You may comment out this entry, but any other modifications may be lost.
deb http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/ stable main
#deb file:///usr/share/local-repository binary/

deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/nuvola-player-builders/stable/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/nuvola-player-builders/stable/ubuntu raring main
# Do not edit this file manually, use Software Sources instead.

deb http://packages.linuxmint.com olivia main upstream import  #id:linuxmint_main

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu raring-updates main restricted universe multiverse

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ raring partner
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/jupiter/ubuntu raring main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu raring main
deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu raring main
```

All tutorials I find don't mention adding any repositories, just to do the usual install. I'm at a loss. Can someone help me out on this relatively simple issue?

Comment: I thought [Mint included Ubuntu's package sources](http://community.linuxmint.com/iso/reports/91/22), and sshfs is definitely in Ubuntu. Please post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*.list`. What version of Mint is this?

Comment: @Gilles Added to post. Mint 15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mint (assuming you are using Mint and not Mint Debian) can use Ubuntu repositories. They should in fact be configured by default but they don't seem to be in your `sources.list`. Add this line to your sources:

```
deb http://packages.ubuntu-com raring main restricted
```

Then run

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

If that doesn't work, download the package from [here](http://packages.ubuntu.com/raring/amd64/sshfs/download) and install using

```
$ sudo dpkg -i sshfs_2.4-1ubuntu1_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Downloading in manually and installing via `dpkg` worked.

Comment: `sudo apt-get update`  is what i want

Answer (score 2):

How about `sudo apt-get install sshfs-fuse` ?

Failing that, what does `apt-cache search sshfs` return?

Comment: No dice. I updated my question (for formatting issues) to show you what I get.

Comment: Nuts. Does your sources.list look decent? ``grep -v '^#' /etc/apt/sources.list``

Comment: `# deb http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu raring-getdeb apps games`.

`-v` returned nothing. That's the contents of the file.

Comment: Let's take this to chat http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26/unix-and-linux

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install sshfs
```

Comment: I always run an update before trying to install a new package. I'm not new to Linux, but I understand why you may have assumed so as I am a new poster to this site. Alas, this results in the same issue. `sshfs` is not being found.

Comment: Maybe there is no port for Mint....in which case you'd have to download/make/install it from the source site.

Comment: I suppose that's a possibility. However, Mint uses a lot of Ubuntu sources, so I would assume a Ubuntu port would work on Mint, no?

Comment: I would find the .deb file and just download that and install using `dpkg -i <sshfs deb file>`.

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar problems installing Ubuntu packages. In desperation, I opened the "Software Sources" application, changed my Ubuntu mirror (to one much closer), selected application source and backports. After updating, I'm able to install applications from Ubuntu repositories. 
I tried to retrace the steps I took to see which step had the effect, but even after undoing everything Ubuntu packages still were in the cache. Thus, I'm not sure which step above fixed the problem.